# Mounting local docker volume to kubernetes pod

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, microk8s, kompose

I am trying to start a postgres pod on microk8s kubernetes cluster. At the moment the postgres container with all its data is started locally on the host machine.

The question is: Is it possible to map the current volume (from local docker volume ) to the kubernetes pod deployment?

I have used `kompose` to convert the `docker-compose.yml` to appropriate `.yaml` files for kubernetes deployment.

The above mentioned command `kompose` creates `postgres-deployment.yaml`, `postgres-service.yaml`, and 2 `persistantvolumeclaims` ( from the volumes mapped in the docker-compose one for the pg_data and the other one for the init_db script).

Do I need to generate `PersistantVolume` mappings alongside the `PersistantVolumeClaims` that were automatically generated by `kompose` and how would they look?

EDIT: Using the yaml below I made 2 `volumes` and 2 `volumeclaims` for the postgres container one for the data one for the init_db script. Running that and then exposing the service endpoints worked.
WARNING: Because the database was running on docker host machine container and kubernetes pod in same time data corruption happened.

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/var/lib/docker/volumes/dummy_pgdata/_data"
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to mount existing docker volume (created independently of Kubernetes) with some data to Kubernetes pod?

Comment: @MikolajS. yes. And i want that volume to be propagated( updated on every change) be that on the host or the kubernetes pod .

Comment: Could you please share a Docker compose `yaml` configuration file? Which `kompose`  command are you using to convert?

Comment: I have edited the post above @WytrzymałyWiktor

Comment: @MikolajS. i have used the kompose convert and provided the docker-compose file. Although i have made some adjustments to the volumes and volumeMounts. Using the Persistant volume from the edit above i have been able to mount the data from an already running postgres db but like i stated a data corruption happened because 2 databases tried to insert into same volume ( the snapshot from the /var/lib/docker/volumes/dummy_pgdata/_data wasnt synchronizing for both of the databases)

Comment: That's normal behaviour. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574863/is-postgres-designed-to-write-to-shared-data-stores/43583234#43583234).

Answer (score 2):

Posted community wiki for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

There is possibility to share same docker volume with the Kubernetes pod by [defining custom PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume) with `storageClassName` and `hostPath` set as below:

```
storageClassName: manual
hostPath:
  path: "/var/lib/docker/volumes/{docker-volume}"
```

**However, there is no possibility to share the same Postgres data files between different Postgres installations.** It may cause data corruption. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43583234/16391991) for more details.